# Is there a way to use the Angular Router Outlet in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, router

I want to use the Angular < router-outlet> inside an Ionic project as an outlet for Components, I want to switch out the components and have not figured out another way then using the Angular Router outlet. My problem is when using the < router-outlet> it behaves like the < ion-router-outlet> (opening the component on a new page, etc.), clearly, I don't want that behavior. Is there any way to disable the < ion-router-outlet> from opening the component on a new Page? Or configuring Ionic to use the < router-outlet> like intended in the first place?
btw. I am using Ionic 5.4.16 and Angular 8.2.14

Comment: What do you mean by "opening the component on a new page"? It opens a new browser tab? Show us how your are navigating between routes in your app.

Comment: ionic is opening the component like a page, with the transition from the bottom, unfortunately i cant show you anything ...

Comment: So you want to route to a new component with no animation, correct?

Comment: I want to show a component inside a router-outlet i don't want to route to that page/component per se, and yes without animation

Comment: The whole point of a `<router-outlet>` is to route to different component views, or "pages". Sounds like you want to hide/show various child components inside of a parent component without using the router. Hard to know what you're trying to achieve without seeing any code.